# connect mysql with java using eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, database-connection

i can connect mysql with java using eclipse in a java application with these statements

```
String unicode = "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ams-competation" + unicode,
                    username, password);
```

and it works good

but my problem is when i tried to connect to mysql with a server application i got this exception

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
what am i doing wrong?thank you all

## Edit

i have added `mysql-connector` already

Comment: Please include the driver jar file in either server or application lib.

Comment: @Santosh i added it already but forgot to tell you, sorry

Comment: @tottiroma: If you have added it, you hadn't got this error message

Comment: @buc really i added it , and i can see it on the Referenced Libraries tab on Eclipse

Comment: Yes you have added it in Eclipse, but you have not added it to the application server.

Comment: i add it on this way , right click on the project , buid path, configuration build path , add external jar file , then select `mysql-connector-java-5.1.13`

Comment: i told you how i add it , is that way wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have not included mysql drive jar in your web project.

put mysql-connector-java.. jar file in your web projects lib folder

Comment: Goto your WEB-IF/lib folder and check if jar is there or not?

Comment: can i copy past the jar to that folder?

Comment: You can also put it directly in your servers lib folder... what web server you are using?

Comment: Yes you can you can copy jar to lib folder directly

Comment: tomkat , i am trying but it take some minutes cos the client is android

Comment: If it doesn't work then directly copy jar into tomcat/lib folder and try again

Answer (score 1):

for that you need to add the  mysql-connector jar in the classpath.

This is because eclipse is not able to find the jar file you specified.

Hence put the jar file in the server`s lib directory

another way is to put jar file it in **/WEB-INF/lib** eclipse itself will notice it and get it.

Comment: it should be added to the server`s lib folder by doing so you can resolve the exception..

Comment: can i add it to that folder using copy past , or i have to do some configuration steps ?

Comment: i really thank you for helping , hope i could accept more than one answer :( , really very thank you for helping , it works

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the MySQL driver to the server?

It depends on the application server where the jar file is needed to be added:

- Apache Tomcat:  `$CATALINA_HOME/common/lib`
- GlassFish server: `GLASS_FISH_INSTALL_DIR\lib`

Or add it the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your web application

Try adding the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar` file (downloadable from: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ ), and restart the server.

Comment: did you add it to the correct location AND restart the server afterwards?

Comment: i add it on this way , right click on the project , buid path, configuration build path , add external jar file , then select `mysql-connector-java-5.1.13`
i can see the jar file on references libraries tab , but not on WEB-INF

Comment: If you just reference it to your project it will NOT be uploaded to the server. You need to add it to the correct folder too.

Comment: and how can i do that ? and what is the correct folder , thank you

Comment: It is in my answer... It depends on your server. If you don't want to use it from multiple applications then you can also put it in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your web application

Answer (score 0):

Add the Connector/J jar file to the server's classpath (or lib folder)

Answer (score 0):

add my sql connection jar file to your project. Its name will be something like "mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar"

Answer (score 0):

connect connector/J 8.0.11 with eclipse oxygen by following line of code.

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "AF", "birru123");

        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
```