# Connect mysql with java

Tags: java, mysql, windows, wamp

I am trying to connect to mysql in java (I use Wamp) so I used the following code : (I'm using Eclipse)

```
package genererPlanning;
import java.sql.*;

public class genererPlanning{
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql";

    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "";

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root", "");
        }
        catch (SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        }
    }
}
```

But it returned me this text :

```
SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql
SQLState: 08001
VendorError: 0
```

Do you know why it does not work?
PS : I looked at theses links but don't find my answer :
- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384710/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost3306)
- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556664/how-to-fix-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dbname-error-w)
- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154065/connect-mysql-with-java-using-eclipse)
- [commentcamarche](http://www.commentcamarche.net/forum/affich-24532247-connexion-java-jdbc)
Thanks for all.

Comment: Do you have the mysql driver lib (jar file) in your build path?

Comment: You miss the `mysql-connector.jar` in your classpazth

Comment: Indeed, this was not mentioned in the tutorial. Can you tell me where to find ( and add) this  .jar please ?

Comment: All the linked questions answer the question - apparently you can't recognize it as an answer. Do you know how to work with jar libraries and/or the Java classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the mysql-connector.jar

Here's the link with instructions as to how to set it to your classpath.

http://code.google.com/p/find-ur-pal/downloads/detail?name=mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar&

Answer (score 1):

You need mysql jdbc connector..download from this [site](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/)